# Error NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, python-2.x

por favor me puede ayudar para resolver este inconveniente:

> NoReverseMatch at /citas/general/modificar/5918 Reverse for
>   'descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita' with arguments '(5918,)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Python 2.7.
Django 1.8

Mi html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="{% url 'descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita' cita.id%}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Imprimir Hoja Amarilla</a>

</div>
```

Mi archivo URL

```
url(r'^(?P<cita_id>\d+)/hojamarilla/pdf/$', descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita,name='descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita'),
```

Mi vista

```
def descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita(request,cita_id):
    realizado_por = request.user#usuario autenticado para guardar en los registros de auditoria
    dispensario =  Perfil.obtener_dispensario(realizado_por)
    cita = None
    try:
        cita = Cita.objects.get(id=cita_id)
        if not Perfil.es_admin(realizado_por) and cita.dispensario != dispensario:
            raise PermissionDenied
    except Cita.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_pdf(request,'citas/templates/pdf/signos_vitales_cita.html',None, {"page_title":u"Signos Vitales","cita":cita})
```

Comment: Hola Roberto, por favor coloca la versión de Django que estás usando

Comment: Hola es Django 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error de **NoReverseMatch** dice que Django no puede encontrar un patrón de URL coincidente para la url que proporcionó en cualquiera de las URL de la aplicación instalada.

Para comenzar a **depurarlo**, debes comenzar dividiendo el mensaje de error.

> NoReverseMatch en /citas/general/modificar/5918

Esta es la url que se está procesando actualmente, es esta url a la que la aplicación está intentando acceder actualmente, pero contiene una url que no puede coincidir, es decir, que no existe.

> Reverse for 'descargar_hoja_amarilla_cita'

Este es el nombre de la URL que no puede encontrar

> with arguments '(5918,)'

Estos son los argumentos que se envian por medio de la URL

> and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Estos son los argumentos de palabras clave que proporciona a la URL.

> 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Estos son los patrones que pudo encontrar en los archivos urls.py con los que intentó hacer coincidir